# Is there a function like cvSmooth for opencv4android?

Tags: android, opencv

I am making an application in android using opencv. To get clear images i wanted to use cvSmooth method, but i think it is not present in opencv4android. It is only available in c/c++. Any help would be appreciated.Thank you

Comment: Usually you want to tag a question with multiple tags such as Android, OpenCV, OpenCV4Android and it'll get more eyes on the question... Especially with how small the OpenCV4Android tag is.

Comment: you have a [documentation problem](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/imgproc/Imgproc.html#GaussianBlur(org.opencv.core.Mat,%20org.opencv.core.Mat,%20org.opencv.core.Size,%20double)) . also, please do **not** look at outdated c-api code, like cvSmooth, or anything containing IplImages, that is all horribly outdated